# How can I parse a text from an URL and put the clean text in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, nltk

I have an Excel file of 147 Toronto Star news articles that I've compiled and created a dataframe. I have also written a Python script that can extract the text from one article at a time. However, I'd like to improve my script so that Python will cycle through all the URLs in the dataframe, scrape the text, append the scraped, stopworded text to the row (or perhaps to a linked text file?), and then leverage that data frame for a classification algorithm and more exploration.

Can someone please help me with writing the loop? (I have no background in programming.. struggling!)

## creating the dataframe

```
url_file = 'https://github.com/MarissaFosse/ryersoncapstone/raw/master/DailyNewsArticles.xlsx'
tstar_articles = pd.read_excel(url_file, "TorontoStar Articles", header=0)
```

## nltk with one article

```
URL = 'https://www.thestar.com/news/gta/2019/12/31/with-291-people-shot-2019-is-closing-as-torontos-bloodiest-year-on-record-for-overall-gun-violence.html'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_='c-article-body__content') 
results_text = [tag.get_text().strip() for tag in results]
sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in results_text if not '\n' in sentence]
sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in sentence_list if '.' in sentence]
article = ' '.join(sentence_list)

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
word_tokens = word_tokenize(article)
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_article = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
filtered_sentence = []

for w in word_tokens:
  if w not in stop_words:
    filtered_sentence.append(w)

clean_tokens = tokens[:]

for token in tokens:
  if token in stopwords.words('english'):

    clean_tokens.remove(token)
```

Comment: since you mentioned that _I have no background in programming_ so rest assured we aren't code writing service or a paid support even. that site built for developers by developers as well. so if you seeking to hire a programmer. so you have to search for code writing service.

Comment: Be nice... Okay lets try answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, most news site has an RSS feed, for the `ww.thestar.com` site, there's https://www.thestar.com/about/rssfeeds.html

Instead of parsing urls from an excel sheet, it's much more convenient to parse the RSS feed =)

Lets try the Toronto news, from http://www.thestar.com/content/thestar/feed.RSSManagerServlet.articles.vancouver.rss

To get the data from a website, one can use the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

In code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://www.thestar.com/content/thestar/feed.RSSManagerServlet.articles.vancouver.rss')
toronto_rss = response.content.decode('utf8')
```

To parse the XML file, lets use the [`feedparser` library](https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/):

```
import requests
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://www.thestar.com/content/thestar/feed.RSSManagerServlet.articles.vancouver.rss')

toronto_rss = response.content.decode('utf8')
feed = feedparser.parse(toronto_rss)

for item in feed.entries:
    print(item.link)
```

Now lets try to fetch the text from each of the link from the RSS using  [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import requests
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://www.thestar.com/content/thestar/feed.RSSManagerServlet.articles.vancouver.rss')

toronto_rss = response.content.decode('utf8')
feed = feedparser.parse(toronto_rss)

for item in feed.entries:
    url = item.link
    response = requests.get(url)
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf8'))
```

And from the `BeautifulSoup` object, there is a nifty `get_text()` function that we can use to extract the text (sometimes this can get somewhat noisy).

Since you already did the hard work for finding the `c-article-body__content` tag that you need to extract the article's main text, we can get the text from:

```
import requests
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://www.thestar.com/content/thestar/feed.RSSManagerServlet.articles.vancouver.rss')

toronto_rss = response.content.decode('utf8')
feed = feedparser.parse(toronto_rss)


url_to_sents = {}

for item in feed.entries:
    url = item.link
    response = requests.get(url)
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf8'))
    article_sents = '\n'.join([p.text for p in bsoup.find(class_='c-article-body__content').find_all('p')])
    url_to_sents[url] = article_sents
```

## That's all nice, the explanation and all but you haven't told me how to put them into a dataframe.

Now the question is why do you need the dataframe? If you only need some keyword tokens per url, then we have to do some processing.

Lets first define the steps needed for preprocessing to get our keywords,

```
1. We want to sentence token, then
2. Word tokenize each sentence
3. Remove the stop words
```

Now there are several options, we can use `scikit-learn` with`nltk` to do (1) , (2) and (3), see https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

But lets keep it simple and just use NLTK for now.

Since the `nltk.word_tokenize()` function implicitly calls `sent_tokenize`, we can just call `word_tokenize` so just (2) and (3) would do.

For now lets simply use `nltk.corpus.stopwords` as stopwords for (3)

So we have this preprocess function:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation

stoplist = set(stopwords.words('english')) | set(punctuation)

def preprocess(text):
    return [word for word in word_tokenize(text) if word not in stoplist and not word.isdigit()]

text = url_to_sents['https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/20/vancouver-fire-says-smoking-caused-the-citys-first-fatal-fire-of-2020.html']

preprocess(text)
```

## Hey, I said, that's all nice and all but I really want a DataFrame...

Okay, okay, there's dataframe but BTW, there's `pandas.DataFrame` is not the only DataFrame library in Python, see https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-an-SFrame-and-a-DataFrame-in-Python

Alright, alright, here's pandas...

First we have the `url_to_text` dictionary, that have the `urls` as keys and the `text` from the article as values.

And lets say we want a dataframe where it keys

a. the URL

b. the text in the article

c. the resulting tokens from the "cleaned" text

So here's a dataframe with (a) and (b):

```
import pandas as pd


urls, texts = zip(*url_to_sents.items())
data = {'urls':urls, 'text': texts}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

[out]:

```
urls    text
0   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/03/26/p...   VANCOUVER—British Columbia’s human rights comm...
1   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/03/08/d...   VICTORIA—At the end of a stark news conference...
2   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/03/08/c...   Teck Resources says it’s baffled over the virt...
3   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/29/t...   SQUAMISH, B.C.—RCMP in Squamish, B.C., are inv...
4   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/26/v...   VANCOUVER—The man who attempted to steal a flo...
5   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/22/g...   VANCOUVER—Canada’s Governor General visited an...
6   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/20/v...   Vancouver philanthropist and former chancellor...
7   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/20/v...   VANCOUVER—A man with mobility challenges has d...
8   https://www.thestar.com/vancouver/2020/02/17/b...   VICTORIA—British Columbia’s finance minister i...
```

## Nice! How about the cleaned tokens?

Since we have a dataframe to work with and function that we want to apply to all the values in the `text` column, we just need to use `DataFrame.apply`, i.e.

```
df['cleaned_tokens'] = df['text'].apply(preprocess)
```

## Awesome!! Wait a minute, did you just do a quotation mark on the "cleaned" text?

Yes, I did. Because what is "clean"?, see https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

- Why do we need to clean the text?
- Do we really need to clean the text?
- What is the ultimate goal of preprocessing the text?

I guess the above questions are out of scope of the original post (OP), so gonna leave them as food for thoughts for you =)

Have fun with the code above!

Comment: Thank you so much, Alvas! I really appreciate the detailed explanation. I'm working on a capstone project as part of a data science certificate program and there is not much supervision or technical assistance from the university, so I've been trying to teach myself Python from the Internet alone. People like you who take the time to really explain and provide links to helpful tutorials are AMAZING!